# React mui-datatables change header color

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm trying to change the head of `mui-datatables`, but it is not working properly.

```
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
...

// here I set the them
const getMuiTheme = () => createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTableHead: {
            root: {
                backgroundColor: "#c1e1ec"
            }
        }
    }
});

...

// rendering
<MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>                                                    
    <MUIDataTable
        title={"Existing Users"}
        data={users}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
    />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

It is not changing the color of the thead. It keep showing a white thead. However, if I inspect the element with Firefox, I can see the following styles for the thead element

```
.MuiTableHead-root {
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color: #c1e1ec;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each child `.MUIDataTableHeadCell-fixedHeader` has own background so you rather should change this class then `.MuiTableHeader-root`

Or in this way which I think is better.

```js
MuiTableCell: {
    head: {
        backgroundColor: "red !important"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code work in functional components?

Answer (score 0):

I found below codes works for me

```
MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
  styleOverrides: {
    fixedHeader: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
  },
},
```

It's reply from https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/162

Answer (score 0):

```
  MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
    styleOverrides:{
      root: {
          backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    }
  },
  MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
    styleOverrides:{
      root: {
          backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    }
  },
  MuiTableFooter: {
    styleOverrides:{
      root: {
          backgroundColor: "wheat"
      }
    }
  },
  MuiToolbar: {
    styleOverrides:{
      root: {
          backgroundColor: "teal"
      }
    }
  }      
}
```